# Cannot parse my SSIS derived column expression

Tags: c#, ssis

Hi this is my first time trying to write a complicated derived column expression. I'm not sure what the problem is as it's a pretty generic error message which doesn't help much,

The expression is:

```
If( [conv_Status] ==10 && [conv_Agreed] == TRUE && [conv_Unagreed] == TRUE) ([conv_Status] == 15) ELSE ([conv_Status] == [conv_Status])
```

And the Error message is as below:

> Error at tblDetail [Derived Column [143]]: Attempt to parse the expression "If( [conv_Status] ==10 & [conv_Agreed] == TRUE & [conv_Unagreed] == TRUE) ([conv_Status] == 15) ELSE([conv_Status] == [conv_Status])" failed. The expression might contain an invalid token, an incomplete token, or an invalid element. It might not be well-formed, or might be missing part of a required element such as a parenthesis.
>
> Error at tblDetail [Derived Column [143]]: Cannot parse the expression "If( [conv_Status] ==10 & [conv_Agreed] == TRUE & [conv_Unagreed] == TRUE) ([conv_Status] == 15) ELSE([conv_Status] == [conv_Status])". The expression was not valid, or there is an out-of-memory error.
>
> Error at tblDetail [Derived Column [143]]: The expression "If( [conv_Status] ==10 & [conv_Agreed] == TRUE & [conv_Unagreed] == TRUE) ([conv_Status] == 15) ELSE([conv_Status] == [conv_Status])" on "Derived Column.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[conv_Status]" is not valid.
>
> Error at tblDetail [Derived Column [143]]: Failed to set property "Expression" on "Derived Column.Inputs[Derived Column Input].Columns[conv_Status]".

Thank you

Comment: is this SSIS or SSRS?

Comment: I am working with SSIS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
conv_Status == 10 && conv_Agreed ==  FALSE  && conv_Unagreed ==  TRUE  ? 15 : conv_Status
```

Comment: A little more explanation: a derived column expression returns a value - it doesn't set anything to a value. Also SSIS doesn't use `if` and `then` it uses `?`  and`:`

Answer (score 0):

```
... ([conv_Status] = 15) ELSE ([conv_Status] = [conv_Status])
```

I believe you want an assignment '=' in these, not comparison '=='.